# Object torn apart in Unity after exporting from Blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

Hi I'm having a bit of trouble importing a map I made in blender into unity. Any ideas? For clarification: I created the map by deleting the faces on the starting cube and built it out through many extrusions and joins, I then separated some parts of it into separate objects so that when I import it into unity, I can apply different materials to the different parts of the mesh. Here is a picture of the
[Broken Mesh in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwaR4.png) and then [The Normal Mesh in Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVwr.png)

Comment: Are both the back and front faces rendered? Make sure you normals point outwards of the mesh in blender.

Comment: @JeanLuc little late but thanks for mentioning, someone from the unity forums managed to give me a hand, just posting the solution here in case anyone who is a blender noob can fix their problem :)